# ERC930 and data upgradability

Tags: contract-upgrading

We are trying to create an upgradeable smart contract. Our first decision is to segregate data and rules. This post focus on data.
I read about the [ERC930](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/930). It proposes a data storage based only in key-value pairs in order to keep the data storage very dinamic to accomodate changes. This ERC is still open.

I understand that we will have no domain-specific schema and it will be the resposibility of the rules to check that the data is really valid. It makes rules more complex and more error-prone. On the other hand, ERC930 makes a contract upgrade easier.

My question is: are you using ERC930 in our project? Are you using other solution to data upgradibility? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at OpenZeppelin SDK to see if this meets your needs for upgradeable contracts: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/sdk/2.5/

If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin.

Comment: Thank you. Open Zeppelin SDK seems really interesting. However, as far as I understand, its upgradeability does not works with dynamic data sets, right? We have mapping in our smart contract, that is why I am looking for ERC930.

Comment: With the OpenZeppelin SDK your upgradeable contracts can include mappings.
https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/updgradeability-with-mappings/1225

Thanks for joining the community at OpenZeppelin.